# php tree class/array structure to breadcrumbs

Tags: php, arrays, tree, class-design, breadcrumbs

Basically i received an API SOAP response of a list of categories in an class format as in array kind of way with CatID, name, parentID, level.

What is the best way to turn this into an array of breadcrumbs for each CatID.

I want to try reduce the number of operation as the array will be created on the fly to populate a drop down menu and there are over a 1000 categories

I apologise in advance for my poor terminology and thank you for any help

Comment: Can you give an example for an input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by converting it into an array and applying a tree algorithm to each element

I know its not very efficent

Comment: Can you please explain your solution?